# Using gravity assitance or turn to return back a spacecraft

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, space

I wonder why [gravity assist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist) is not also used to return missions back to Earth?
I assume the space shuttle is too expensive with its accessories and could be a money and time saving to reuse it, particularly if used for recording a huge amount of data along its mission.

Is this feasible in theory and what complications would be to evaluate this type of application?

Answer (score 1):

Gravity assist might be used in some cases, but generally it is incompatible with the mission required.

The space shuttle was only used in low earth orbit.  There is nothing in that region that can be used for gravitational assist.

Missions to the moon could launch toward the moon on free-return trajectory.  But they had to leave that trajectory to line up for lunar orbit.  Once in lunar orbit, the craft is already down in the gravity well and can't make use of gravity assist to return.

For outbound flights, passing by Jupiter can allow an assist.  But for a return, you'd have to get back to Jupiter in the first place, and that is usually prohibitively expensive.

I can't think of any good cases where gravity assist would make a substantial difference to allowing a return mission.